# Encryption Failing with error Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string

Tags: encryption, base64, private-key, encryption-asymmetric

I am trying to encrypt a `PRIVATE KEY` with a passphrase so I can save the file to disk. But the encryption method is throwing the exception: "`Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string`".

The Encryption method is (it's a `2048bit key length`):

```
                    public static string Encrypt(string plainString, string key, int keySize = Keysize.SymmetricKeyLength)
                {
                    var aesEncryption = new RijndaelManaged
                    {
                        KeySize = keySize,
                        BlockSize = 128,
                        Mode = CipherMode.CBC,
                        Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7,
                        IV = Convert.FromBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(key)).Split(',')[0]),
                        Key = Convert.FromBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(key)).Split(',')[1])
                    };

                    byte[] plainText = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainString);
                    ICryptoTransform crypto = aesEncryption.CreateEncryptor();
                    // The result of the encryption and decryption            
                    byte[] cipherText = crypto.TransformFinalBlock(plainText, 0, plainText.Length);

                    return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherText);
                }
```

I am converting the Private Key to a `Base64` string before passing it down to the encryption method using this method:

```
        public string EncodeTo64(string plainString)
        {
            var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainString);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
        }
```

The Private Key is:

```
<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>rhtMjLTg17sYlns4ktTow9eeuwRNra0+AO2HqESGmA8zkxe/uOv0msXzzLWUWzdPaTxi4OV+PNVPBAHW1C0CTT/33NlvipkJ1Qr5BJK1TiVZCMInshe4OL/7GNnPUPhsS6DZ/c/fnWLoxtRMUmkKgpWmtXGs7ZSoIztdJ1bgiygJWCDvrHTokVIzDaNzRonZIFk41Qt4rPofCEawjkR639OcOfazNlmU9JjvRs3ysoYghDzvVuLvJvPK7zCMzpJMQFQE7cipezXbumTqSdp20mQXJduDbD9qLKXOvcTw+2KPoNlUp+IRQrOmSf+Dl4Vxi+8+UuOH7KDLz7yL9IOPeQ==</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent><P>2AHey3Tgg/K8M16kv6bWk1BsFGhg9xXZw2ruVhS620gyvPBtWBuOU+tzPRnEplw+Kp9jua7Nu4JkKwpQdZvRqeW42d/UCergkdNRheM3DXYj/xQNs8a1diTNe72elCsCfSHr1z/vgN+Cp+v8O4BzX07TrHeGOOP/7HWhE6setxM=</P><Q>zld05TyC/vVI2sBgaR/iYyXdUO3iIIwkGSyOmfDr1dbCKFR7btGLEsW9EpCGibyGPbAk4jA9BLU1bviBM8iH6mxWn1s4UAiIha0QSM2K9NWUPi67FELl6Fs2eLHl9qRniBhAOBCGArklail+YadKCtUsrWhfJgvO3uxkp+fg9MM=</Q><DP>sziaCmVnAxObY2PbfciHsKLBig0wptHSZHmMVo/MmbRFpM43aysx5B8u9jszFnTif6rPq3iF6lY9lhhwuaQXScf4n40++RuQSG307gmf2+Nx6mpRFCCC3wuaElk6AeXNotVKQMYjieHpHjqGhTgGgcV9i1OAYiOKbD8M7qzER1E=</DP><DQ>FEazzfLsTHF9/0D4OFxRurx1ywYVOm2K/o5KVQY/pnu8CIqEtpcQu3+C3Ngm4FIOPvGYLkHfPR8xaP4ydAw4juimenJUTkkIYVpoRz8rcHOsZY/iAlOwk+yipamVl28AXXdEmD3HbW0UKCJ7sMznkbjw8vlWoD54zZ8dJQK8MFE=</DQ><InverseQ>FUFC9v5B1mXxbbiD4WZm/KGIa3XO5+K9FwSRroj8wNMt+JY5aMS8SfUcrZMvUXfHS9+3BYXBIlxPBUm6HnfB7yPE9S0LFzRpB7APbJ0HVIlSjMS9ZdkqxShGAEufYx/FKQXomJlEXXkpgAiDnUnCR2H+ekQf1YpQUzol2KedwfA=</InverseQ><D>gEhc/s/HWyzf0QC5jnaRirs0mVdyZKVhKg3aBoF3KlMJDThSa05vzBpOqGaiCROXz1JPCKYPfYMt1SYFxA/lwkV/u5n6NYTNWcvb7yKptAqQr4Ne/Dm94xKRUJ4rwt1H7fF2rSyc9roKCXYjRhVfSRg63TYE1IjT2iHDYVkB2YVPK67O2O7YmQXeUHMRMVwXpnZCvweleRKlYbVFx2N7ZEC1TZoUn2RKsiBEem1eNSwnLa4wUf1Xl8Q8h+ziY0GnREf9JpTZhJW7f4MKsqLyOMgmoskKiIOWlnwq/b01ivB2CXFhxiiVuNUPPiMuJu6bhljeulvKl32kEzLAFxm2gQ==</D></RSAKeyValue>
```

and the resulting Base64 string from the above conversion method is:

```
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
```

Apparently this Base64 string is invalid and the encryption fails.

Can anybody see where I am going wrong?

Comment: can we get the stack trace or the line on which the exception occurs?

Comment: The error occurs in this line:
`var aesEncryption = new RijndaelManaged
                        {
                            KeySize = keySize,
                            BlockSize = 128,
                            Mode = CipherMode.CBC,
                            Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7,
                            IV = Convert.FromBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(key)).Split(',')[0]),
                            Key = Convert.FromBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(key)).Split(',')[1])
                        };`

Comment: The Base64 text is the text shown above in the initial submission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed! It appears the error was a little misleading (or likely I was being stupid!) and it looks like it was NOT the plain text for encryption that was the cause of the exception but the password/passphrase.

I found another app I was using this method in and found the KEY was the problem. I was passing a plain text password in initially, then I changed this to a SHA-256 hash of the password when this was in fact not a valid key.

I added these two methods (the later of which I found on here):

```
            public static string AesKeyFromPassword(string password, int keySize = Keysize.SymmetricKeyLength)
        {
            byte[] passwordByteArray = CreateKey(password);

            var aesEncryption = new RijndaelManaged
            {
                KeySize = keySize,
                BlockSize = 128,
                Mode = CipherMode.CBC,
                Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7,
                Key = passwordByteArray
            };

            aesEncryption.GenerateIV();
            string ivStr = Convert.ToBase64String(aesEncryption.IV);
            string keyStr = Convert.ToBase64String(aesEncryption.Key);
            string completeKey = ivStr + "," + keyStr;

            return Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(completeKey));
        }

        private static byte[] CreateKey(string password)
        {
            var salt = new byte[] { 1, 2, 23, 234, 37, 48, 134, 63, 248, 4 };

            const int Iterations = 9872;
            using (var rfc2898DeriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt, Iterations))
                return rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes(32);
        }
```

This now takes the plain text password/phrase and generates a valid encryption key which I then use in the `Encrypt` method.

Thank for your help guys!  I can now securely store the Private Key! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your Base64 string appears to be valid.  When I decode it I get some recognisable XML for RSA:

```
<RSAKeyValue>
  <Modulus>rht ... PeQ==</Modulus>
  <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
  <P>2AH ... txM=</P>
  <Q>zld ... 9MM=</Q>
  <DP>szi ... R1E=</DP>
  <DQ>FEa ... 8MFE=</DQ>
  <InverseQ>FUF ... wfA=</InverseQ>
  <D>gEh ... m2gQ==</D>
</RSAKeyValue>
```

That has added newlines and is abbreviated for clarity.

Was that what you were expecting?  If it was then I suggest that you check each of the included pieces of Base64 for errors.  Alternatively, it may just be that your initial piece of Base64 is too long.

Comment: What is the length of a Base64 string? I converted the PRIVATE KEY to base64 then tried encrypting it with AES256 so I didn't thing there was an actual limit to the size of the plain text for the cipher method?

Comment: There should not be a limit, but there may be some requirement on one of the methods you are using.  Experiment by trying short Base64 strings first, gradually making them longer.  Remember that the XML characters are not valid in Base64, so you need to remove them if you are decoding the individual pieces within the RSA key.

Comment: OK, I removed the private key and passed "TEST-VALUE" down. This converted to "VEVTVC1TVFJJTkc=". Now the error is "The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters."

Comment: For me, `VEVTVC1TVFJJTkc=` decodes to "TEST-STRING".  You need to check *exactly* what you are passing.  Does it have some UTF-8 characters at the start for instance.  I suspect that something is getting in to your strings and giving Base64 indigestion.

Comment: Sorry!! Typo - it IS TEST-STRING.